# Sharing single application across a 2 subdomains in IIS7

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7

I have an application that is currently deployed (ex. www.example.com ).  However, now we have a "secure" subdomain, which will take all of the requests that need to be encrypted (ex. secure.example.com).  The site that is at www.example.com is currently mapped to C:\inetpub\example.com\wwwroot\, and I've mapped secure.example.com to C:\inetpub\example.com\wwwroot\secure.

However, since secure.example.com was setup as a new website within the IIS Manager, when the secure site is visited, it displays an error since there is no web.config associated with this website; however, this is the way I want it since I want this to be a part of the application that is in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really meant to do was just right click on the web site for example.com and edit the bindings. In there you can add host names to that site.

Make sure you add them for port 443 which is SSL.

Comment: Yes, you use a single container but have a host header to enfore SSL for the second domain record.

Answer (score 0):

Map both the IIS virtual directories/web sites to the same directory, and check that are both using the same IIS application name.

(Not tried this, but can't recall seeing anything to say it would not work.)